# wxpython ListCtrl can't change selected item colour

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

As the title, I don't understand why I can't change selected item background color. Here my code...

```
self.listaFatture = wx.ListCtrl(self, size=(frame.GetSize().Width - 30, frame.GetSize().Height - 250), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
.....

self.listaFatture.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.SelezionaFatturaColore)

.....

def SelezionaFatturaColore(self,event):
    print('Selezionato')
    index= event.GetIndex()
    self.listaFatture.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, 'gray')
    self.listaFatture.SetItemTextColour(index, 'black')
```

The event is fired but the colors doesn't change

Thanks in advance to all that try to help me

Comment: The colours will not be seen to have changed while the item is `selected`, as this is governed by your OS. However, the colours should be seen to have changed, if you select another item. Is this what to are referring to, if so, there is not much you do about it?

Comment: I don't know if I undestand, but If I put the change of color in the unselect event, this works...the problem is that I want only one row selected but one time the color is changed I cannot reset it and so there are N selected row. I'm very sorry for my english, I hope youn can undestand me. in any way thanks a lot

Comment: Selecting a "thing" on your desktop or in your program, highlights that "thing". Your operating systems current `Theme` will define a selected items look. You cannot override it in your program. You can code for it but it will be overidden by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, I don't know if is a bug or not.

I set a variable with -1 and after, when I select a row I remember the index, I deselect it ad after I set the color...

More simple to read the code...

```
self.lastSelected = -1
....
self.listaFatture.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.SelezionaFatturaColore)
....
def SelezionaFatturaColore(self,event):
    print('Selezionato')
    index= event.GetIndex()
    if self.lastSelected > -1:
        if self.lastSelected % 2 == 0:
           self.listaFatture.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.lastSelected, wx.Colour(255,255,255,255))
        else:
            self.listaFatture.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.lastSelected, wx.Colour(152,245,255,255))

    self.listaFatture.SetItemState(index, 0, wx.LIST_STATE_SELECTED)

    self.listaFatture.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, wx.Colour(128,128,128,255))
    self.listaFatture.SetItemTextColour(index, wx.Colour(0,0,0,255))
    self.lastSelected = index
```

Comment: I think that you could use `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED` to achieve the colour change.